# Not able to add background image for a particular DIV in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a webpage like the following:

[image]

I am trying to add a small background image in the marked section below:

[image]

I tried the following code for the DIV

```css
.king {
background-image: url(../img/banner-lg.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="king">
</div>
```

But the background image is not coming into display, can anyone help me with this.

Comment: I would start from checking that
a) the image actually exists in the location you're pointing to
b) the container has any height at all; maybe the content in this particular div is floated or absolutely positioned? Quite hard to tell following just the code you gave here.

Comment: the image is there, the div doesnt hav any height,

Comment: Then this is the reason why you can't place the background image there. It might as well be rendered, but with the height of 0 pixels, so not really showing. If you can create a fiddle with the full code for this section, we can try to find out why the container has no height and solve the issue :)

Comment: If the .king div has 0 height.... My Hobbies content where it's wrapped in?
If you have that content inside the div with class king, it must be height at least as the content inside it (if the content is not wrapped inside a div with absolute positioning)

Comment: @Dario If the content wrapped with the king div is floated to the left (and not cleared), the height will still be 0.

Comment: For a better answer we need to see the html and css that you use for that section :)
I think that it's a bootstrap col-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in my snippet if you set some width and height static to the div, the image is showed up.

Be sure that your div has height so he can show your image.

Be sure that the image url() is corrected, did you try to show an external image like http://via.placeholder.com/200x200

```css
.king {
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/200x200");
  /*If you comment background-repeat the image will be repeated*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  /*if you comment width and height you just see a grey line taken by <p> tag
    if you comment the <p> you don't see nothing*/
}
```

```html
<div class="king">
  <p> Some text Here </p>
</div>
```

Some good resources:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

PS: I see in the resources that the form is `url('the_path_image')`... did you try with '' ?

**EDIT**

Add an example with no repeated image.

Now the container div is 500x500 and image is 200x200.

If we comment the `background-repeat: no-repeat;` the image will be repeated for the full div area

Comment: your answer worked, but its coming many images, how can i make it only come once

Comment: Edited my answer with a background-repeat example.
Let me know if it's work

Answer (score 1):

try to write like this:-

```
.hero-image {
      background-image: url("/images/photographer.jpg");
      background-color: #cccccc;
      height: 500px;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Where in the world are you coming up with "hero-image" or "photographer.jpg"?!

Comment: i just gave u the idea  to customize code like this .Not like that i have written all the code according to u and u just copy and paste it to ur code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to set background image.

```
.king {
background-image: url('../img/banner-lg.jpg');
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 100%;
height: 0;
padding-top: 66.64%; /* (img-height / img-width * container-width) */
            /* (853 / 1280 * 100) */
```

}